# vSphere automation SDK for REST resources usage

Tags: sdk, vsphere

I am actually trying to develop a monitoring application for the vCenters of my company. I am using Symfony/PHP, but is it possible with the vSphere automation SDK for REST to retrieve some informations like vm's CPU usage, vm's memory usage or host's memory usage ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of right now, there are no stat based properties which can be pulled from the vSphere REST API.